# Login error message in modal

Tags: php, authentication, bootstrap-modal

I created a login modal form with username and password. Successful login will redirect to my admin dashboard. Is there a way I can put the error message "Username and Password is incorrect" when trying to login incorrect credentials below my login modal form?

My modal form:

```
  <li class="active">  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Login</a></li>
                  <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="loginmodal-container">
                    <h1>Login</h1><br>
                  <form action="" method="post" name="login">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Script:

```
<?php
    require('db1.php');
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){

        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); 
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: view.php");
            }else{
                echo "<div class='login-modal'>Username or password is incorrect.<br/>Click here to <a href='index.php'>Login</a></div>";
                }
    }else{
?>
```

Comment: You could send the check as an AJAX request. You should parameterize your query, not strip slashes, and use an updated hashing algorithm.

Comment: form and php is in same file ?

Comment: @JYoThI yes form and php is in same file

Comment: AJAX is the way to go or else every time you submit the form, your page reloads, and your modal will close.

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the error message like below and if the username password is wrong it will go to the else part. So you can open a modal using `$('#login-modal').modal('show');` .

**In form:**

```
 <h1>Login</h1><br>
  <?php if(isset($error_msg)){ echo $error_msg; } ?>
 <form action="" method="post" name="login">
 ...
 </form>
<?php if(isset($script)){ echo $script; } ?>
```

**PHP:**

```
if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: view.php");
        }else{
            $error_msg = "<div class='login-modal'>Username or password is incorrect</div>";
            $script = "<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#login-modal').modal('show'); }); </script>";

            }
```

Note 1: First the PHP code then the HTML code . This is so you can able to set `$error_msg` in html form .

**Update 1** : Used Prepared statement and stored the script in a variable and echo after HTML and jQuery include  like this.

```
    `
    <?php
        require('db1.php');
        session_start();

        if (isset($_POST['username'])){

            $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); 
            $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
            $password = md5($password);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username=? and password=?";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
                    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
                    $stmt->execute();
            $result=$stmt->get_result();
            $rows  = $result->num_rows;
            $stmt->close();
            //$rows=0;
            if($rows>0){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("Location: view.php");
                }else{
                    $error_msg = "<div class='login-modal'>Username or password is incorrect</div>";
                    $script =  "<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#login-modal').modal('show'); }); </script>";
                    }

        }
    ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <li class="active">  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Login</a></li>
                      <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="loginmodal-container">
                        <h1>Login</h1><br>
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg)){ echo $error_msg; } ?>
                      <form action="" method="post" name="login">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
                      </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>

    <?php if(isset($script)){ echo $script; } ?>`
```

**Your code looks like it has SQL injection possibilities, so try to use prepared statements or PDO to avoid SQL injection.**

Comment: I did what you said but it still doesnt work. The new form and php sscript looks like this: https://pastebin.com/WBTn36Ws

Comment: first php code then html code . so only you can able to set $error_msg in form  change like this   order <?php .... ?>   <form>...</form> @JayDoe

Comment: @JayDoe are you writing `PHP` code and ajax in the same file

Comment: @JYoThI , then his php code is working i have tried it myself

Comment: @JayDoe did you tried my steps ? . it's easy to do .

Comment: @JYoThI it is still not working, im getting errors. is  the position of my code correct?

Comment: "unexpect error {" in the line you give <?php isset($error_msg){ echo $error_msg; } ?>

Comment: in above original post why you use else part for if (isset($_POST['username'])){ }else {  //html or here is it ?   } @JayDoe

Comment: change the line like this <?php if(isset($error_msg)){ echo $error_msg; } ?> @JayDoe and i tried your code in my local it worked perfect

Comment: @JYoThI i tried your update1 and now i can't login there is an error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in the line containing  $rows  = $result->num_rows;.

Comment: @JayDoe you still havent figured this out? Have you tried the AJAX way?

Comment: @JYoThI Thank you! Tried that and it works, but is there a way when i click incorrect credentials in login the modal won't close. Im really sorry for asking this. I just started learning php. Thanks again

Comment: modal don't want close means . you need ajax call like @CodeGodie  #code

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier, use jQuery and AJAX:

1. give your `form` an ID and a div container for your results message:

   ```
   <form id="login">
       <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
       <div id="results"></div>
   </form>
   ```
2. move your PHP code to another file and give it a name like `processLogin.php`
3. load jQuery:

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
4. create the JS to use AJAX like so:

   ```
   $('form#login').submit(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: 'processLogin.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(msg){
                // you would need to modify your PHP's echo results 
               if(msg){
                   $("#results").html(response);
               }else{
                   window.location.href = "view.php";
               }
           }
       });
       return false;
   });
   ```

Comment: you need to remove the type="submit"  or use  preventDefault() to prevent the form submiting otherwise your page will  reload.

Comment: I have to disagree. The type="submit" is needed in order to trigger jQuery's `submit()` function, and to prevent the default im using `return false;`